# Modifying style (line width/color) of vector layer in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, style, pyqgis-3

I'm currently updating some python code from QGIS 2.18 to QGIS 3.4

in 2.18 i used the following code :

```
#First off I created a virtual layer using an sql query here

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query=....", "virtual" )
    
# Then I assign the properties of the polyline layer here

props = { 'width' : '3', 'color' : '255,0,0' } 
sl = QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry.instance().symbolLayerMetadata("SimpleLine").createSymbolLayer(props)
s = QgsLineSymbolV2([sl]) vlayer.setRendererV2( QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2( s ) )
```

I know there have been a number of changes in QGIS 3 for exemple`QgsSymbolLineSymbolV` has become `QgsLineSymbol`and `setRendererV2` which becomes `setRenderer`. So, with the help of this [blog](https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2014/03/04/symbology-of-vector-layers-in-qgis-python-plugins/) this [GitHub](https://github.com/JonathanWillitts/common-qgis-2-to-3-plugin-fixes)the [API](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html) and the most recent [doc](http://file:///C:/Users/luke.howarth/Documents/SIG/QGIS-testing-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-en.pdf) on the QGIS site, I've put the script below together...

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("t_alpha")[0]

single_symbol_renderer = layer.renderer()

symbol = single_symbol_renderer.symbol()

symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255, 0, 0))
symbol.setWidth(3)


layer.triggerRepaint()

qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

But this returns an error:

> AttributeError: 'QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer' object has no attribute
> 'symbol'

I've dug through the doc and otherwise tried to remodulate the code a bit but I'm a bit stuck (i'm still learning Python).

Comment: Your code works if the initial style uses _simple symbology_. If it was _categorised_ then that error would appear. You should probably set which style you want to use and then apply the relevant settings. The [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#appearance-symbology-of-vector-layers) should help.

Comment: @Joseph Thanks, that helps - i was trying to modify a layer which had a categorised style! Ok I'll dive back into the doc - so i need to modfiy the layers style setting first (i.e. catagorised to simple) and then apply the above script?

Comment: Yes or you could modify it via your script if you add the logic. I think the example code in the docs I linked to shows how you can apply a simple symbology to your layer without you having to manually change it.

Answer (score 6):

In QGIS 3.4.x is:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("t_alpha")[0]
layer.renderer().symbol().setWidth(0.7)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: To update the layer tree view: iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())

Answer (score 4):

In QGIS 3+:
For single symbology renderer:

`renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol)
iface.activeLayer().setRenderer(renderer)
iface.activeLayer().triggerRepaint()`

For categorized symbology:
create categories with `QgsRendererCategory` [doc](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Renderer/QgsRendererCategory.html)
create renderer with QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer and the categories [doc](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/other/QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer.html)
and

`iface.activeLayer().setRenderer(renderer)
iface.activeLayer().triggerRepaint()`